# Get network interface information

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I know there is ifconfig command that we can list network interface info.
but i want to get information in the following pattern

```
Interface_Name IP_Address Net_Mask Status(up/down)
```

for example

```
eth0 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 down
```

I tried ifconfig and grep command but can't get right pattern.
There is another command or some trick to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is good :D but let see in bash:

```
Interfaces=`ifconfig -a \
    | grep -o -e "[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]*[ ]*Link" \
    | perl -pe "s|^([a-z]*[0-9]*)[ ]*Link|\1|"`

for Interface in $Interfaces; do
    INET=`ifconfig $Interface | grep -o -e "inet addr:[^ ]*" | grep -o -e "[^:]*$"`
    MASK=`ifconfig $Interface | grep -o -e "Mask:[^ ]*"      | grep -o -e "[^:]*$"`
    STATUS="up"
    if [ "$INET" == "" ]; then
        INET="-"
        MASK="-"
        STATUS="down";
    fi
    printf "%-10s %-15s %-16s %-4s\n" "$Interface" "$INET" "$MASK" "$STATUS"
done
```

It is quite straightforward.

This is done on an assumption that '`ifconfig interface` does not show an internet address' to means that the interface is down.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`ifconfig` has two output modes -- the default one in which it gives a LOT more output, and the short `-s` one in which it gives less (or, rather, picks different bits of info from what you'd like). So what about taking ifconfig in the default mode and cherry-picking the specific info you want in a script (python, perl, ruby, awk, bash+sed+..., whatever floats your boat;-).  E.g., w/Python:

```
import re
import subprocess

ifc = subprocess.Popen('ifconfig', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
res = []
for x in ifc.stdout:
  if not x.strip():
    print ' '.join(res)
    del res[:]
  elif not res:
    res.append(re.match(r'\w+', x).group())
  else:
    mo = re.match(r'\s+inet addr:(\S+).*Mask:(\S+)', x)
    if mo:
      res.extend(mo.groups())
    elif re.match(r'\sUP\s', x):
      res.append('up')
    elif re.match(r'\sDOWN\s', x):
      res.append('down')

if res: print ' '.join(res)
```

and the output should be as you desire it (easy to translate in any of the other languages I mentioned, I hope).

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the `ip` command. The following example focuses on globally valid IPv4 addresses outputting them in CIDR notation.

```
# list interfaces that are up
ip -family inet -oneline addr show scope global | awk '{ printf "%s %s up\n", $2, $4 }'

# list interfaces that are down
ip -family inet -oneline link show scope global | grep ' DOWN ' | sed 's/\://g' | awk '{ printf "%s none down\n", $2}'
```

(Note that the desired netmask representation is omitted in the example.)

As `ip` is quite powerful, you might be able to find an even cleaner solution using other parameters.